# RuntimeException Could not scan for classes inside "database/factories" Laravel

Tags: laravel, charts

i need to install Laravel charts in my project. after installing

```
composer require consoletvs/charts:6.*
```

I have this error :

```
[RuntimeException]
Could not scan for classes inside "database/factories" which does not appear 
to be a file nor a folder
```

So after when i copy my provides and allias in App folder, i got :

```
Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider' not found
```

Anyone  can help please ?

Answer (score 13):

I've just had this error crop up. It was because I'd removed all of the files from the database/factories folder. The options to fix were either to add a stub factory file back into the folder. The UserFactory.php that comes with Laravel will do.

```
<?php
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

The alternative is to remove from composer.json

```
"classmap": [
    "database/factories"
],
```

Comment: You can find the file from Laravel's official repository here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/database/factories/UserFactory.php

Answer (score 0):

When a composer installation doesn't work right I check that composer itself is updated.

[Run composer's self-update command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate-)

```
 php composer.phar self-update
```

Comment: Error : Could not open input file: composer.phar :/

Comment: Im on version 1.7.2 now. But i still have the error with database/factories